# Why does mouse pointer stop at the screen edge?

Tags: python, mouseevent

When the mouse pointer is at the screen edge, if we continue to move the mouse to that direction, it will stay at the edge.

Why's that?
I tried to understand this with a mouse hook in python, and find out that the pointer's position *was* moved to that direction, but then bounced back to edge.

I'm trying to hack around and see how this happened, can I make the mouse pointer stay at the position out of the screen and not bounce back to the edge? If so, could it be done in a driver?

```
In [71]: def mousehook(evt):
    ...:     print(f"mousehook, {evt}")
    ...:

In [72]: import mouse

In [73]: mouse.hook(mousehook)
Out[73]: <function __main__.mousehook(evt)>

mousehook, MoveEvent(x=997, y=1080, time=1536040579.9038901)            <----y=1080, mouse position is at the bottom of my screen now, and I'm moving it down
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=996, y=1090, time=1536040579.9278252)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=996, y=1092, time=1536040579.9378557)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=998, y=1094, time=1536040579.9446943)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1002, y=1097, time=1536040579.951711)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1006, y=1102, time=1536040579.960732)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1013, y=1110, time=1536040579.9687536)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1018, y=1113, time=1536040579.9737678)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1022, y=1120, time=1536040579.9817884)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1023, y=1121, time=1536040579.990813)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1022, y=1120, time=1536040579.9978318)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1016, y=1132, time=1536040580.005868)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1009, y=1124, time=1536040580.0128717)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=1002, y=1139, time=1536040580.0249045)           <----y=1139, cross the screen edge 
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=996, y=1121, time=1536040580.0289156)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=994, y=1118, time=1536040580.0399437)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=992, y=1108, time=1536040580.0459607)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=989, y=1108, time=1536040580.0509746)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=986, y=1103, time=1536040580.0600011)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=983, y=1098, time=1536040580.0670166)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=982, y=1095, time=1536040580.0750391)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=982, y=1092, time=1536040580.0840635)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=982, y=1086, time=1536040580.0910902)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=982, y=1083, time=1536040580.0991023)
mousehook, MoveEvent(x=982, y=1080, time=1536040580.1091292)            <----y=1080, position mouse back to the edge
In [74]: mouse.unhook_all()
```

Comment: Mouse movements may well tell the cursor to move to coordinates that do not exist, but if they are off-screen, there is no point in the GUI actually moving the cursor off-screen. This could lead to a situation where the cursor is lost off-screen in any direction. Why would you want to achieve this?

Comment: I'm thinking about simulating some kind of VR experience with mouse-like devices. A screen is just a part of the VR world to be presented. Say there're two screens, one in the front and one at the back. A calibrated mouse-like device can move pointer on the screen at its pointed direction, and you have to actually turn 180 degrees and point it at the screen at the back to make the pointer move there. So this could provide some sort of VR interaction.

Comment: Ah I see. Interesting idea.